# How to sequence numbers in text while looping

Tags: python

I'm trying to reach a way to print numbers in a specific way but I can't, my code here

```
for i in range(7): # 7 it could be a string length for an example
    print("letter"+str(i)+",letter"+str(i+1)+"|letter"+str(i+1)+",letter"+str(i+2)+";")
```

will print:

```
letter0,letter1|letter1,letter2;
letter1,letter2|letter2,letter3;
letter2,letter3|letter3,letter4;
letter3,letter4|letter4,letter5;
letter4,letter5|letter5,letter6;
letter5,letter6|letter6,letter7;
letter6,letter7|letter7,letter8;
```

What output I need is like this:

```
letter0,letter1|letter1,letter2;
letter2,letter3|letter3,letter4;
letter4,letter5|letter5,letter6;
letter6,letter7|letter7,letter8;
letter8,letter9|letter9,letter10;
letter10,letter11|letter11,letter12;
letter12,letter13|letter13,letter0;
```

and `letter0;` should be the last one always

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
r = range(7)

for a, b in [(i, i + 1) for i in r][::2]:
    if b + 1 <= len(r):
        c = b + 1
    else:
        c = 0
    print(f"letter{a},letter{b}|letter{b},letter{c}")
```

result:

```
letter0,letter1|letter1,letter2
letter2,letter3|letter3,letter4
letter4,letter5|letter5,letter6
letter6,letter7|letter7,letter0
```

Comment: by iterating over half of the data don't you need to double the original input? `range(2*7)`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `end` argument when using print.

```
where = 0
for i in range(14):
    for _ in range(2):
        where += 1
        print(i, "|", end = "", sep = "")
        if where == 4:
            where = 0
            print(";")
```

Comment: it should print "0|1|1|2|;--snip--" instead of "0|0|1|1|;--snip--"

Comment: Oh yea, remove the for _ in range(2): then

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like that would work:

```
for i in range(7): # 7 it could be a string length for an example
    e = i + 1
    f = i + 2
    g = i
    if i > 0:
        g += i
        f += i
        e += i
        if f == 14:
            f = 0
    print(f"letter{g}, letter{e}|letter{e},letter{f};")
```

Comment: That's great! but the last line it should be "letter12, letter13|letter13,letter0;" instead of "letter12, letter13|letter13,letter14;"

Comment: It should not depend on a specific number, after 14 it will not print 0

Answer (score 0):

Add readability with a string formatter. Use modulo arithmetic to fix the index of the last iteration.

```
n = 7

template = 'letter{},letter{}|letter{},letter{};'
counter = 0
for _ in range(n):
    s = template.format(counter, counter+1, counter+1, (counter+2) % 2*n)
    print(s)
    counter += 2
```